# Irreguler control flow with http.post

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, http

Hi folks after getting suspense response from service in exceptional cases control is not going to if(success== response) block not sure how to handle it
Any help would be apreciated

### Code:

```
$http.post(ipAddr, data, config).success(function(data) {
  if ("failure" == data.response.status) {
    $scope.check = true;
    $rootScope.msg = data.response.message;
    $scope.loaderShow = false;
    $rootScope.applicationNo = data.response.applicationNo;
    if ("production" == $rootScope.environment) {
      //dataLayer.push({ event: "denialNOAA.html"});
    }
    window.location.href = "#!/denialNOAA";
  }
  if ("success" == data.response.status) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

### issue service response is:

```
{
  "response": {
    "reqTrackCode": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX", 
    "payload": {
      "pdaAccountNbr": "XXXXXXXXXX", 
      "docStatus": "XXXXXX", 
      "applicationNo": "XXXX", 
      "pdaRouting": "XXXXX", 
      "payFrequency": "XX", 
      "noOfInstallmants": "XX", 
      "mbDetails": [
        {
          "isIncomeProofRequired": "Y", 
          "isIdProofRequired": "Y", 
          "isAddressProofRequired": "Y", 
          "isBankStatementRequired": "Y"
        }
      ], 
      "appStatus": "PENESIGN", 
      "loanAmount": "1000.00", 
      "scheduleDetails": [ ]
    }, 
    "custUniqueId": "XXXXXXXXX", 
    "errorCode": "CMS-APPLYLOAN-01", 
    "message": "Request Successful", 
    "status": "success"
  }
}
```

### Working response;

Hi folks after getting suspense response from service in exceptional cases control is not going to if(success== response) block not sure how to handle it
Any help would be apreciated

### Code:

```
$http.post(ipAddr, data, config).success(function(data) {
  if ("failure" == data.response.status) {
    $scope.check = true;
    $rootScope.msg = data.response.message;
    $scope.loaderShow = false;
    $rootScope.applicationNo = data.response.applicationNo;
    if ("production" == $rootScope.environment) {
      //dataLayer.push({ event: "denialNOAA.html"});
    }
    window.location.href = "#!/denialNOAA";
  }
  if ("success" == data.response.status) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

### issue service response is:

```
{
  "response": {
    "reqTrackCode": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX", 
    "payload": {
      "pdaAccountNbr": "XXXXXXXXXX", 
      "docStatus": "XXXXXX", 
      "applicationNo": "XXXX", 
      "pdaRouting": "XXXXX", 
      "payFrequency": "XX", 
      "noOfInstallmants": "XX", 
      "mbDetails": [
        {
          "isIncomeProofRequired": "Y", 
          "isIdProofRequired": "Y", 
          "isAddressProofRequired": "Y", 
          "isBankStatementRequired": "Y"
        }
      ], 
      "appStatus": "PENESIGN", 
      "loanAmount": "1000.00", 
      "scheduleDetails": [ ]
    }, 
    "custUniqueId": "XXXXXXXXX", 
    "errorCode": "CMS-APPLYLOAN-01", 
    "message": "Request Successful", 
    "status": "success"
  }
}
```

Working finely with below response;

```
{"response":
       {"reqTrackCode":"20190321T1313461R1376846"
       ,"payload":
        {"pdaAccountNbr":"55011337961026528"
        ,"docStatus":"PENDOCGEN"
        ,"applicationNo":"22939513"
        ,"pdaRouting":"113024164"
        ,"payFrequency":"MON"
        ,"noOfInstallmants":"12"
        ,"mbDetails":[{"isIncomeProofRequired":"Y"
        ,"isIdProofRequired":"Y"
        ,"isAddressProofRequired":"Y"
        ,"isBankStatementRequired":"Y"}]
        ,"appStatus":"PENESIGN"
        ,"loanAmount":"1000.00"
        ,"scheduleDetails":[]}
        ,"custUniqueId":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        ,"errorCode":"CMS-APPLYLOAN-01"
        ,"message":"Register Application  - Request Successful"
        ,"status":"success"
```

}}

Comment: seems like it should be `if("success"==data.response.payload.status)`

Comment: but in some cases its working fine with same data

Comment: you have different data structures? based on the JSON you posted here , `data.response.status` shouldn't be defined. when you console your condition you get true or false?

Comment: nevermind ... your *unique* formatting is deceptive `data.response.status` IS correct

Comment: @FedeSc - OP's deceptive formatting fooled you :p

Comment: oops..!! it's success only i wrote wrongly while asking question...Am not going into success block after success status...neither success or failure i wrote  one more block with error.with the above respone only i got problem

Comment: @JaromandaX You're right haha ! my bad ! sorry :)

Comment: @FedeSc - you should've seen the comment I left before I realised :p

Comment: Could you explain in breif please

Comment: Finally came to one conclusion that either customer might have closed his browser or server got stopped...Thanks for the efforts